# Magento : Grouped Product with Configurable Product Mandatory to Add to Cart

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1, shopping-cart, grouped-products, option

I have a few **grouped products**, with more than one **configurable products** (with different colour as simple product) associated as sub products.

The problem is, because simple product (colour) in a configurable product is mandatory to select when add to cart. So when customer click on grouped product in my shop, he must also select at least one colour for each configurable product in order to proceed. but this is not what I want.

as shown in this image, a customer must select one of colour for both configurable products in order to buy this grouped product. How do I make it so customer only need to select just one configurable product and not all products.

[image]

Comment: have you tried custom options instead of using simple products with attributes?

Comment: we have too many products to change to the custom options. we'd rather rewrite javascript validation if no standard way to do it in Magento.